# Return single value from forEach kotlin

Tags: kotlin, foreach, return

Im wondering, whats the best way to accomplish following:

```kotlin
val asd = listOfStuff.forEach {
    if ( it.name == name ) return it
}
```

so that asd will be first value of list where `it.name equals name`

I know there is multiple ways, but since im using kotlin, why not go kotlin way..
Im just having hard time finding right words to google this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [`firstOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) like this:

```
val asd = listOfStuff.firstOrNull { it.name == name }
```

Comment: thaank you, tried with find, this is better, much thanks

Comment: `find` uses `firstOrNull`: `public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.find(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    return firstOrNull(predicate)
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can `find` elements matching a given condition, like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val listOfStuff = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

    val asd = listOfStuff.find { it == "1"}

    print(asd)
}
```

Output will just be `1`.

Note that this will find the first value matching the condition or return `null` if the element is cannot be found, so the answer given by @forpas is better if you don't know for sure the element is present.

Comment: `find` and `firstOrNull` do exactly the same thing. `find` is a [controversial case of redundancy](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5185) in the standard lib to make the function easier to find for people coming from certain functional languages.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, didn't know... Then my answer is not that worse than the accepted one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Array.find` function?

You can find more information here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/index.html

In your example you should get the element with:

```
val asd = listOfStuff.find(name)
```

I'm not sure how your array looks like. But it seems like you have multiple objects with properties (name). Then you probably need to do something like:

```
val result: asd? = listOfStuff.flatMap { it.name }.firstOrNull { it.name == "name" }
```